# Is $Y=\{x \times y \ | \ y=0\} \cup \{x \times y \ |\ x > 0, y=\frac{1}{x}\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ a sepraration of Y in X??

Tags: general-topology

I came across this example of connectedness in a [LSU PDF](https://www.math.lsu.edu/system/files/08_Topology_IV_Connectedness_Moshe_Cohen.pdf), and I'm trying to understand it.

The topolocal space is $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the subspace $Y$. Is this an example of a separation in $Y$ in X? If so, how can I show that there exists two open sets in Y, and then show they are disjoint?

Thoughts?

Comment: What is $A$? Also, what is "this" in the sentence "is this an example of a separation in $Y$"? I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry should have been Y. And I think I messed up the terminology really bad.  I'm looking to show that there is a pair of sets that are a separation of Y in X, and I think the PDF is suggesting the two disjoint sets that show there is a separation of Y in X are directly defined in Y=...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, $Y$ is not connected. You can see this in several ways:

---

One way of showing it is to see that the sets $A=\{x \times y \ | \ y=0\}$ and $B=\{x \times y \ |\ x > 0, y=\frac{1}{x}\}$ are both open, since

$$A=\{(x,y)| y<\frac1{2x}\}\cap Y\\
B = \{(x,y)| y>\frac{1}{2x}\}\cap Y$$

---

Another way, following the link you provided, you could show that $A$ does not contain any limit point of $B$, and vice versa.

Comment: In the example, should Y=$\{x \times y \ | \ y=0\} \cup \{x \times y \ |\ x > 0, y=\frac{1}{x}\}$ or  $Y=(x,y)\ | \ y=0\} \cup \{(x,y) \ |\ x > 0, y=\frac{1}{x}\}$ (so basically asking if $x \times y$ is the correct notation.

Comment: @Learner I think you just wrote the same thing in two different notations. The second one is more common, the first seems strange to me.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.